# 401 unauthorized for programmatically created azure application while accessing resources

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I have to register azure application on behalf of user. I used Azure Graph API to perform following actions:

1. create **Application** with required resources
2. create **Service principal** for registered app
3. create **OAuth2PermissionGrant entity** for service principal with required scopes

After that I successfully acquired access_token for created upp. But unfortunately 401 Unauthorized was returned while I tried to access O365 resources with that token. Without any json'ed error!!

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Expires: -1
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2015 11:58:59 GMT
>
> ... thats it!

Next I went to Azure portal - there was all OK. After few experiments I noticed that access_token becomes valid after any changes via portal (even cosmetic).

So I compared tokens using JWT decoder and found that Scopes were not included:

[picture - token BEFORE changes in portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orsms.png)

[picture - token AFTER changes in portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtheg.png)

Also I noticed that OAuth2PermissionGrant entity was overwritten after changes.

---

I used following web resources and libraries:

1. library for authorization:ADAL
2. library for Access to Graph API: www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
3. complete list of GraphClient examples can be found here github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/Program.cs

Below I attached code that creates app programatically. Also I can attach fiddler logs and other info.

```
        ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient;
        string clientSecret = "...hidden...";
        string name = "O365 auto created client";
        try
        {
            activeDirectoryClient = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsUser();

            var appObject = new Application
                {
                    DisplayName = "O365 auto created client",
                    Homepage = "https://sign",
                    LogoutUrl = "http://logout1.net"
                };
            appObject.IdentifierUris.Add("https://localhost/demo/" + Guid.NewGuid());
            appObject.ReplyUrls.Add("https://localhost/demo");

            var officeAccess = new RequiredResourceAccess
            {
                ResourceAppId = "c5393580-f805-4401-95e8-94b7a6ef2fc2", // OfficeManagePlatform 
                ResourceAccess = new List<ResourceAccess>
                    {
                        new ResourceAccess
                            {
                                Id = new Guid("825c9d21-ba03-4e97-8007-83f020ff8c0f"),
                                Type = "Role,Scope"
                            },
                        new ResourceAccess
                            {
                                Id = new Guid("e2cea78f-e743-4d8f-a16a-75b629a038ae"),
                                Type = "Role,Scope"
                            },
                        new ResourceAccess
                            {
                                Id = new Guid("594c1fb6-4f81-4475-ae41-0c394909246c"),
                                Type = "Role,Scope"
                            }
                    }
            };
            appObject.RequiredResourceAccess.Add(officeAccess);


            var passCreds = new PasswordCredential
            {
                StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
                Value = clientSecret,
                KeyId = null,
                CustomKeyIdentifier = null
            };
            appObject.PasswordCredentials.Add(passCreds);

            try
            {
                await activeDirectoryClient.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(appObject);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Application Creation exception: {0} {1}", e.Message,
                    e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "");
            }


            ServicePrincipal newServicePrincpal = new ServicePrincipal();
            if (appObject!= null && appObject.AppId != null)
            {
                newServicePrincpal.DisplayName = appObject.DisplayName;
                newServicePrincpal.AccountEnabled = true;
                newServicePrincpal.AppId = appObject.AppId;
                newServicePrincpal.Tags.Add("WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp");
                try
                {
                    activeDirectoryClient.ServicePrincipals.AddServicePrincipalAsync(newServicePrincpal).Wait();
                    Console.WriteLine("New Service Principal created: " + newServicePrincpal.ObjectId);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service Principal Creation execption: {0} {1}", e.Message,
                        e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "");
                }


            }




            OAuth2PermissionGrant permissionObject = new OAuth2PermissionGrant();
            permissionObject.ConsentType = "AllPrincipals";
            permissionObject.Scope = "ServiceHealth.Read";
            permissionObject.StartTime = DateTime.MinValue;
            permissionObject.ExpiryTime = (DateTime.Now).AddMonths(12);

            // resourceId is objectId of the resource manage.office.com             // in this case objectId of AzureAd (Graph API)
            permissionObject.ResourceId = "52f62a75-b73d-496a-9bfa-1bf41339a90a";   // "52620afb-80de-4096-a826-95f4ad481686";

            //ClientId = objectId of servicePrincipal
            permissionObject.ClientId = newServicePrincpal.ObjectId;
            try
            {
                activeDirectoryClient.Oauth2PermissionGrants.AddOAuth2PermissionGrantAsync(permissionObject).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("New Permission object created: " + permissionObject.ObjectId);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Permission Creation exception: {0} {1}", e.Message, e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException.Message : "");
            }

            return new ClientCredential(clientId: appObject.AppId, clientSecret: clientSecret);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I've got a feedback from azure dev team - this feature is not fully implemented. Some user activity required to finish app creation.

Comment: Hi UNdedss, you mention that you got some feedback from the Azure team. Did you find a way to solve this in code without needing the user log on to the management portal and performing a change on the application properties?

Comment: @RasmusW 
It is still not implemented. I didn't find any solution suitable for production. But I noticed some comments that Visual Studio's service principal can do it. Try to investigate further.

Comment: It looks like this feature still does not work :-(

Comment: In your ResourceAccess objects you specify both Role and Scope. According to Graph API doc: "Possible values are "scope" or "role"." I had actually never seen that an app permission and delegated permission could both have the same id.. But this one does. But you only want one of them right?

Comment: @juunas project was finished and we solved this problem in another way. Regarding your comment - maybe, but very doubtfull. We copypasted app config from existing app created via portal.